# Opencv how to read single frame from camera

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to read single frame from camera but it hang my program and make the *imshow window* not responding , so any idea how to read single frame so that my vision module can process it

Here is my code:

```
 cv::VideoCapture VideoCapture;
 // Frame read from Camera will be stored in CamFrame MAT
 cv::Mat CamFrame;

// Open camera
VideoCapture.open(0);

if(!VideoCapture.isOpened())  // Check if we succeeded
{
    with for loop it not hang the imshow model  
  //   for (;;){

    // Read frame from Camera
    VideoCapture.read(this->CamFrame);
    // check if we succeeded
    if (this->CamFrame.empty()) {
        qDebug() <<  "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
        break;
    }
    cv::imshow("live frame ",this->CamFrame);

     // }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [waitKey()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey) after imshow(). As documentation says:

> **Note** :This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and
>   handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event
>   processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes
>   care of event processing.

```
cv::VideoCapture VideoCapture;
 // Frame read from Camera will be stored in CamFrame MAT
 cv::Mat CamFrame;

// Open camera
VideoCapture.open(0);

if(!VideoCapture.isOpened())  // Check if we succeeded
{
    with for loop it not hang the imshow model  
  //   for (;;){

    // Read frame from Camera
    VideoCapture.read(this->CamFrame);
    // check if we succeeded
    if (this->CamFrame.empty()) {
        qDebug() <<  "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
        break;
    }
    cv::imshow("live frame ",this->CamFrame);
    waitKey(0);

     // }
}
```

**Note:** If you want to use imshow for continuous frames, you can assign an if case with a specific waitKey() or also in while()